# small differences in scipy spline interpolation vs natural and matlab splines

Tags: scipy, interpolation, spline

I am using scipy.interpolate to make a spline interpolation based on the following data:

```
xs=[0.041984,0.374045,0.625954,0.874045,1.374045,1.870229,2.362595,2.862595,3.358778,3.854961,4.354961,5.354961,7.343511,8.835877,9.335877,10.33587]
ys=[14.145,14.235,14.275,14.24,13.91,13.7,13.57,13.52,13.55,13.56,13.45,13.44,13.46,13.44,13.45,13.45]

f = interp1d(xs,ys,"cubic")
```

now f(10) gives 13.4589, while I obtain 13.4525 with the "numerical recieipes" code in C (natural spline)

Can you please explain the difference?

I tried also with Matlab which gives 13.4583

Comment: Probably a slight difference in how the data at either end are padded out to allow the spline fit.  From the numerical recipes, did you select it to be "natural" or to have a specified first derivative? For scipy.interp1d, did you specify the _kind_ string or not (note that the default is not a spline)?

Comment: I selected natural in numerical receipes, and specified cubic for interp1d

Comment: interp1d (splmake, really) does not produce a "natural" spline --- it does not require that the 2nd derivatives are zero at the edges of the interpolation interval.

Answer (score 0):

Despite their attractive name, "natural" cubic splines are rarely used. The usual way to deal with two extra degrees of freedom in the cubic spline construction is to impose the "not-a-knot" condition, which requires the third derivative to be continuous at the first and last interior knots; in effect, these knots are no longer knots because the polynomial coefficients do not change  at those knots.

The cubic spline returned by `interp1d` is not-a-knot, and so is the spline constructed by Matlab (by default). To construct a natural spline with SciPy, use `make_interp_spline` with boundary conditions `[(2, 0)], [(2, 0)]`, meaning the 2nd derivative must be zero at both ends. Example:

```
xs=[0.041984,0.374045,0.625954,0.874045,1.374045,1.870229,2.362595,2.862595,3.358778,3.854961,4.354961,5.354961,7.343511,8.835877,9.335877,10.33587]
ys=[14.145,14.235,14.275,14.24,13.91,13.7,13.57,13.52,13.55,13.56,13.45,13.44,13.46,13.44,13.45,13.45]

spl1 = interp1d(xs, ys, "cubic")
l, r = [(2, 0)], [(2, 0)]  # natural spline boundary conditions
spl2 = make_interp_spline(xs, ys, k=3, bc_type=(l, r))

t = np.linspace(min(xs), max(xs), 500)
plt.plot(t, spl1(t) - spl2(t))
plt.show()
```

The plot of the difference of two splines shows that the difference is only visible near the ends of the interpolation range; this is where the effect of the boundary conditions is strongest.

[image: difference]

The values at 10:

- 13.458277949 for knot-a-not spline
- 13.4524921744 for natural spline